# Reducing Logical Reads for a Join - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

The logical reads for T1 are around 130,000 but 1.4 million for T2. T2 holds around 2.8 million rows. Are there any ways in which i can reduce these reads from a performance stand point? Example query below:

```
SELECT T1.[ID],T1.[Name],T1.[City],T2.[Number]
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
```

Comment: Can you provide DDL, for both tables, **including** relevant indexes?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, logical reads (pages touched by the query) is a valid measure of work done by a query to return the result. Query and index tuning can reduce logical reads and thereby improve query performance.

Comment: try the compiler join hints, and why not?  Give it a go.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DanGuzman So you're saying that a join can prevent the DB from having to do a logical read?  Shame on me for not knowing this, the result of spending all my time on reporting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, useful indexes on columns specified in `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses can reduce logical reads, improving query performance. There are often trade-offs between too many indexes (increasing storage and maintenance overhead) and t0o few (query performance) so some judgement is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize this query:

```
SELECT T1.[ID], T1.[Name], T1.[City], T2.[Number]
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T2
     ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID];
```

By creating an index.  The appropriate index is on `T2(ID, Number)`.  You could `include` number in the index rather than having it as a key, but I'm guessing that it is probably useful for the index in other queries.

Comment: index (ID) INCLUDE(Number)

Comment: Thanks, index is my last resort. I just wondered if there is any way to improve the query itself but i guess its pretty basic already

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, why is indexing a last resort? Without a useful index, the SQL Server optimizer's hands are tied and a full scan will be required.

Comment: why do you call an index a last resort?  You've got things like compiler join HINTS you could try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-2017   Maybe you've got a critical space issue - I did encounter a boss who banned new indexes once, and in fact a large customer has pretty much done that, for fear of upsetting things.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I have to ask as well, why is adding an `INDEX` the last resort? Generally the first point of call, when suffering from poor performance on a simple query, is to look at the index(es). What do you have against an index?

Comment: I would use indexes first but i've been advised to try and keep indexes below 5 per table as much as possible. Im assuming this lowers the load on maintenance jobs etc

Answer (score 2):

Create two nonclustered indexes:

- On T2, index the field *ID* and include the field *Number*.
- On T1, index the fields *ID* and *Name* and include the field *City*.

This way, the query is covered by the indexes (SQL Server will only access index pages).

If this does not dramatically improve query performance, try to use a "hint" for the JOIN:

```
SELECT T1.[ID], T1.[Name], T1.[City], T2.[Number]
FROM T1
LEFT HASH JOIN T2 ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
```

Kindly share the results (no. of pages accessed).